# OnsenUiの確認ダイアログ内の処理が即時反映されない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

いつもお世話になっております。開発環境Monacaです。Monaca公式ガイドブックのサンプルアプリに、追加機能としてOnsenUiの確認ダイアログを実装したものの、その処理内容が画面に即時反映されません。

●対象サンプルアプリ
Monaca公式ガイドブック10-2「バーコードスキャナーアプリ」
https://ja.monaca.io/book/zip/10-2.zip

●追加した機能
スキャンした履歴をクリアする際に、確認ダイアログを開くようにする。

●問題点
リストを全てクリアする確認のダイアログで「OK」を押しても、画面上で変化しない（リストが表示されたまま）。タブで画面を一度切り替えるとクリア後の画面になっている。

→クリアボタンをおしたら、すぐにリストが消えるようにしたいです。

アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

【追加（変更）ソース部分】

```
$scope.clearHistory = function() {
　　ons.notification.confirm({
    　message: '全てのデータを削除しますか？',
    　title: '確認',
    　buttonLabels: ['Cancel', 'OK'],
    　primaryButtonIndex: 1,
    　cancelable: true,
    　callback: function(index) {
        if(index == 1){
            //OKクリック時
            $scope.history = [];
            $scope.saveHistory();//!!この処理が即時反映されません!!
        }                
    }            
});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.$apply()`を実行して更新してください。

```
//OKクリック時
$scope.history = [];
$scope.$apply();
$scope.saveHistory();
```